# Android - How to fetch tweets of a person from Twitter API

Tags: android, twitter

I googled to get tweets of a person from `Twitter API (JSON Object).`

But i didn't get any perfect solution to it.

I tried using `QueryResult`, but its showing either `# HASH_TAG` or `@ Tag`.

Is there any way to get tweets of a person `(I have the User ID and Screen Name).`

Here is the code I tried:

```
ConfigurationBuilder builder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
builder.setOAuthConsumerKey(TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY);
builder.setOAuthConsumerSecret(TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET);

User user;
AccessToken accessToken = new AccessToken(TWITTER_ACCESS_TOKEN, TWITTER_ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET);
Twitter twitter = new TwitterFactory(builder.build()).getInstance(accessToken);

List<twitter4j.Status> statusList = new ArrayList<>();
Query query = new Query("%23tarak9999");
query.setCount(20);

QueryResult result = twitter.search(query);
statusList = result.getTweets();
```

Thank You

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example Activity setting up a UserTimeline:

```
import com.twitter.sdk.android.tweetui.TweetTimelineListAdapter;
import com.twitter.sdk.android.tweetui.UserTimeline;
public class TimelineActivity extends ListActivity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.timeline);
TwitterConfig config = new TwitterConfig.Builder(this)
        .twitterAuthConfig(new
TwitterAuthConfig(TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY, 
TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET)).build();
Twitter.initialize(config);
final UserTimeline userTimeline = new UserTimeline.Builder()
        .screenName("twitterdev")
        .build();
final TweetTimelineListAdapter adapter = new TweetTimelineListAdapter.Builder(this)
        .setTimeline(userTimeline)
        .build();
setListAdapter(adapter);
 }
}
```

and the corresponding XML layout timeline.xml, showing attribute values without resource references for clarity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<TextView android:id="@id/android:empty"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
          android:text="No Tweets"/>
<ListView android:id="@id/android:list"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="0dp"
          android:layout_weight="1"
          android:divider="#e1e8ed"
          android:dividerHeight="1dp"
          android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"/
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Replace screenname with you screen name

Comment: `Must initialize Twitter before using getInstance()` this is the error i got after implementing your answer. Any modifications needed in above answer ?

Comment: You must initialize twitter before using this. I gave you the answer to read the tweets from specific user. Assuming you already initialized twiiter sdk. I'll update my answer. Plz use the updated code above.

Comment: I made some search on twitter analysis and answered to my question and its working fine

Answer (score 1):

The answer mentioned above by `Malik Ahsan` is throwing an error

`RunTimeError: Must initialize Twitter before using getInstance()`.

Adding the below lines solved the issue:

```
TwitterConfig config = new TwitterConfig.Builder(this)
            .twitterAuthConfig(new TwitterAuthConfig(TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY, TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET)).build();
Twitter.initialize(config);
```

The above lines to be added above

`UserTimeline userTimeline = new UserTimeline.Builder().screenName("SCREEN_NAME").build();`